# .htaccess rule skipping a subfolder in the redirect

Tags: regex, .htaccess

Here’s my rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^dev/([^/]+)/ dev/index.php?test=$1 [NC]
```

However, instead of changing the url from `www.test.com/dev/asdf` to `www.test.com/dev/index.php?test=asdf`, what happens instead is that we get `www.test.com/index.php?test=asdf`. So basically the `dev/` part in the rewrite rule is just skipped.

The intended effect is to have `dev/variable/` be parsed as a get variable, so it gets changed to `dev/index.php?test=variable`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be several things: `.htaccess` is in the wrong folder, incorrect RewriteBase set up elsewhere, or the url is getting rewritten by another rule.

Make sure to place the `.htaccess` in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder (the one above `dev`).

Then try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^dev/([^/]+)/ dev/index.php?test=$1 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this `mod_rewrite` ruleset instead:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(dev/index.php)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^dev/?([^/]*)$ /dev/index.php?test=$1 [R,L,NC]
```

The second line which has the `RewriteCond` is to ensure that you don’t have an endless loop of `dev/[something]` going to `dev/index.php` which will result in an internal server error. The `R` flag sets a real redirect to `/dev/index.php?test=` rather than just passing parameters behind the scenes.

And one benefit of the `R` flag is you debug this stuff using `curl -I` from the command line like this to show you the actual headers being returned. I’m using `localhost:8888` on my local MAMP, FWIW:

```
curl -I localhost:8888/dev/asdf
```

Now the resulting headers are as follows:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Sun, 29 Jun 2014 04:15:31 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.23 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.23 OpenSSL/0.9.8y DAV/2 PHP/5.4.10
Location: http://localhost:8888/dev/index.php?test=asdf
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

The `HTTP/1.1 302 Found` means that a `302` temporary redirect will be happening. And the `Location` header shows the proper final destination of `http://localhost:8888/dev/index.php?test=asdf`.

Then in my test setup, I placed a `dev/index.php` file that contains this simple PHP code:

```
<?php

echo '<pre>';
print_r($_GET);
echo '</pre>';

?>
```

So a call to `localhost:8888/dev/asdf` creates the final URL of `http://localhost:8888/dev/index.php?test=asdf` and the output of that PHP script shows that the `asdf` is properly being passed as desired:

```
Array
(
    [test] => asdf
)
```